# How to check if a coupon code is a free shipping one?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, coupon, free-shipping

I'm working with Magento 1.9.2.

I need to check (via code) if a coupon is a "free shipping" one: how can I do it? I searched everywhere online but I didn't find a solution yet.

I know there are two tables used to store coupons: `salesrule` and `salesrule_coupon`. I noticed that my "free shipping" coupons seem to be recognized by the following combination of columns:

- `simple_free_shipping == 2` and
- `coupon_type == 2`

Is this a safe way to check the "free shipping" of a coupon?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please explain what you want to do with this coupon code, so that i can give you proper logic for this?

Answer (score 0):

with your guidance I knew how to find it.

please look at the following

> Mage_SalesRule_Model_Resource_Rule_Collection

and

> Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule

as you see you have the method `getSimpleFreeShipping` so you have to find the correct model which is a sales rule model and go from there:

```
<?php

$rootPath = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
require_once $rootPath . 'app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$shopping_cart_rules = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/rule_collection');
echo "<pre>";
foreach ($shopping_cart_rules as $rule) {
    echo "RULE ID:" . $rule->getRuleId()."<br/>";
    echo "coupon code ID:" . $rule->getCode()."<br/>";
    echo "Simple free shipping:" . $rule->getSimpleFreeShipping()."<br/>";
}
echo "</pre>";
```

Then:

```
<?php

$rootPath = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
require_once $rootPath . 'app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$shopping_cart_rules = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/rule_collection');
echo "<pre>";

foreach ($shopping_cart_rules as $rule) {
    if( $rule->getSimpleFreeShipping()==1):
         echo "coupon code ID:" . $rule->getCode()."is used for free shipping<br/>";
    endif;
}
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: It seems my free shipping coupons don't respect the  `$rule->getSimpleFreeShipping() == 1` condition :/ Thank you anyway!